# What is the meaning of className variableName; variable declaration in java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java. I am unable to understand what className variableName; means.
e.g in given code what does Node Next; mean?

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
        }
   }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Answer (score 0):

className- here is Node,variableName the name of your variables,like for int->data,for Node->next.
Node next - is a pointer to the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Names are necessary for referencing and reusing of classes, instances, etc.

`Next` is a pointer to another node, this is usually done when you create a data structure respectively a list.

```
class **Node (class name)** {
    int **data (variable name)**;
    Node **next (variable name)**;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```